# Canon EOS 550D video

Tags: video

Hi Im using a Canon EOS 550D & for some reason when ever i try shoot video it stops recording a couple of seconds in. I'm using a Scandisk  Ultra SDHC 4 32GB card, i've tried formatting before hand but it still does the same thing.
please could you assist
Thanks

Comment: It's not the same camera, but it's almost certainly the same problem.

Comment: With a bit more searching you might have found the question [Why does my Canon DSLR stop recording video automatically?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20180/why-does-my-canon-dslr-stop-recording-video-automatically)

Answer (score 0):

The reasons for an automatic stop are either reaching the 30 minute limit (thank you European Union video camera tax that ends up impacting what's available to most of the rest of the world), hitting the 4gb file limit (file system limit for the OS on the camera), the sensor is overheating (high usage + temperature) or the buffer is being used up (memory card is too slow).

Based on your description of the problem, the first two do not sound like the issue, however you could either be hitting an overheat or a buffering issue.  A class 4 card is a bit slow for recording HD video, but I'd still expect more than a few seconds, particularly for a SanDisk card which should actually be giving you speeds for a class 4 card.  (Some less reputable manufacturers routinely sell cards marked faster than they actually test in the real world.)

I'd first try getting a faster card and if that doesn't work, I'd make sure you are using the camera in a cool area and see if that gives a longer run time.  It's also possible there could be something wrong with the camera that is complicating things, but a slow memory card is most likely the problem.